# Flake 8's equivalence to ESLint max-statements

Tags: python, coding-style, flake8, linter

[max-statements](http://eslint.org/docs/rules/max-statements) in Javascript ESLint offers a really good enforcement for small, modualized and readable functions. I was hoping to find something similar in Python Flake8 lint but so far I've had no luck. Is there a way of configuring Flake8 to encourage small functions?

Comment: Looks like there's a cyclomatic complexity checker, but it's disabled by default. `--max-complexity` is the command line flag for it or `max-complexity =` in a config file. A value of 10 is recommended. It's not *quite* the same but can encourage similar habits.

Answer (score 3):

To expand on @kindall's comment,

Flake8 does not provide a statement checker, but it does have two ways of calculating cyclomatic complexity of functions and methods.

[Cyclomatic complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclomatic_complexity) uses statements and branches to determine the complexity of a function so this will likely result in even simpler functions than what you might see in JavaScript. This is because `if/elif/else` structures will add to the complexity, as will `for` and `while` loops.

To enable the "built-in" cyclomatic complexity enforcement, you can use `--max-complexity`. There are, however, alternatives to the `mccabe` project. For example, if you `pip install radon` that adds it's own cyclomatic complexity checking to Flake8 and will run when you run Flake8.